# Cookies I sent from my nodejs and Express backend are not being added to network requests from the front-end tho they're visible in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I sent a jwt token as cookies after login. It is visible in the cookies section of the browser but when I make network requests, the cookies is not added to the request as such I'm unable to access protected routes from my frontend. But when I use something like Postman or insomnia, I'm able to access the cookies and access protected routes

My backend login

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  let { email, password } = req.body;

  email = email.trim();

  if (!email || !password)
    return next(errorHandler(400, "All fields are required"));

  if (email === "" || password.trim() === "")
    return next(errorHandler(400, "No field can be left blank"));
  try {
    const user = await UserSchema.findOne({ email });
    if (!user)
      return next(
        errorHandler(
          404,
          "Incorrect username or password, would you like to sign up instead?"
        )
      );

    if (user.fromGoogle)
      return next(
        errorHandler(403, "You already signed in with a different method")
      );

    const checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

    if (!checkPassword) return next(errorHandler(400, "Wrong password"));

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      { id: user._id, fromGoogle: user.fromGoogle, accType: user.accountType },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    const { _id, ...others } = user._doc;

    res
      .cookie("access_token", accessToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(_id);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

My React frontend

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!email || !password || email.trim() === "" || password.trim() === "") {
      dispatch(loginFailure(null));
      return setInputError("All fields are required");
    }

    dispatch(loginStart());

    try {
      const res = await backendConnection.post("/auth/login", inputValue, {
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "include",
      });
      dispatch(loginSuccess());
      localStorage.setItem("clientId", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      window.location.href = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        loginFailure(
          error.response.data
            ? error.response.data.message
            : "Something went wrong"
        )
      );
    }
  };
```

Please I'll be very glad if someone helps me out